# Processing 20x20 image before training for machine learning

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I have 10,000 examples 20x20 png image (binary image) about triangle. My mission is build program, which predict new image is whether triangle. I think I should convert these image to 400 features example, but I don't know how convert fastest.

Can you show me the way?

[Here are a image .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBwYr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad  as you dont specify which technologies you are using , but in general you need to create a vector from an array , that depends on your tools , for example if you use python(and the numpy library) you could use flatten().

```
image_array.flatten();
```

If you want to do it manually you just need to move every row to a single  row.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct. Yet I want to add something to it:

The example image that you provided is noisy. This is rather problematic as you are working with only binary images. Therefore I want to suggest preprocessing, such as **gaussian filter** or **edge detection**. Denoising will improve your clustering algorithms accuracy stronlgy (to my knowledge).

One important question: 
What are the other pictures showing? Do you have to seperate triangles from circles? You will get much better answers if you provide more information.

Anyhow, my key message is: Preprocessing is vital for image-processing.